# logoff for lack of iteration, express js, node js, passport js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

Is it possible with expressjs and nodejs to log off the application for lack of iteration after a certain period?

My application uses express-session and js passport

My session setup is expressed below, but if the user does not use the application for about 20 minutes and tries to perform an in-app operation, it redirects the login screen. But I wish this behavior were automatic.

**express-session current**

```
app.use(session({
    key: 'user_sid',
    secret: 'reistur',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {maxAge: 2592000000}
 }));
```

Comment: I think people do one of two things: use a socket for real-time communication that keeps track of auth or poll the server for "am I still authenticated" using AJAX requests. After you get that going it's a simple window.location = '/login'

Comment: I understood, thanks for the reply.